# Can I consolidate multiple MYSQL databases into one database via a script?

Tags: mysql

I'm using MYSQL 5.7.19 on an ubuntu server. 
Say I have 3 databases (db_1,db_2,db_3) and I create an empty database called all_db

Is there a way to copy my databases to all_db where db_1,db_2,and db_3 fall under all_db with the format of all_db.db_1_tablename1,all_db.db_2_tablename1, etc?

Comment: This is a development task. What languages/dev environments are you familiar with?

Comment: php, unix shell scripting

Comment: You could do most/all of this simply using the dumps (mysqldump), a bit of sed and vi!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution to my problem. 
I wrote a select statement from the information_schema database that pulls all of the databases and their tables. I then ran these commands via CLI.

select concat('alter table ', table_schema, '.', table_name, ' rename NEWDB.', table_schema, '_', table_name, ';') from tables

Thanks for the advice, help.
Hopefully this helps someone in the future.

Comment: You can mark your own answer as correct. You might have to wait a wee while, but, as you say, it may help others - no points for marking it correct, though :-( . However, by marking it correct, you may get other visitors who will upvote it, giving you points :-) p.s. welcome to the forum!

Comment: Thanks! I have to wait 2 days to update it. Thanks for the help again. talking about vi and sed got me going in the right direction with this problem.

Comment: Are there any foreign keys in your tables ???

Comment: There are not. If there were, would they have not copied over? I noticed the views didn't copy over but recreating those isn't much of a hassle in my instance.